# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. - Strange behavior

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

This is a very strange behavior and I don't know how to fix it.

I have an Activity as a Presenter (In a MVP Architecture).
When the activity starts, I attach a Fragment as a View. The fragment itself is very simple.

```
public class CurrentSaleFragment extends BaseFragment {

private MainMVP.SalesPresenterOps salesPresenterOps;
private SaleAdapter adapter;
private ListView lv;


@BindView(R.id.btn_sell)
FloatingActionButton btnAdd;

public static CurrentSaleFragment newInstance(){
    CurrentSaleFragment fragment = new CurrentSaleFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt(LAYOUT_RES_ID, R.layout.fragment_quick_sale );
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
protected void init() {
    super.init();
    lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_sale);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_sell)
public void addToSale(View view){
   mPresenter.moveToFragment(SellProductFragment.newInstance());
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    salesPresenterOps = (MainMVP.SalesPresenterOps)context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    salesPresenterOps = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
}
```

The BaseFragment from which this fragmend extends :

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements MainMVP.RequiredViewOps, View.OnClickListener,
    LoaderRequiredOps{

protected View view;
protected MainMVP.PresenterOps mPresenter;


protected final static String LAYOUT_RES_ID = "layout_res_id";

@Override
public void showOperationResult(String message, final long rowId) {
    Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(
            R.string.see, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onOperationResultClick(rowId);
                }
            }
    ).show();
}

@Override
public void showSnackBar(String msg) {
    Snackbar.make(view, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void showAlert(String msg) {}



protected void onOperationResultClick(long rowId){}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mPresenter = (MainMVP.PresenterOps)context;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.view = inflater.inflate(getArguments().getInt(LAYOUT_RES_ID), null);
    init();
    return view;
}

protected void addToClickListener(View ... params){
    for (View v : params){
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}

protected void init() {
    if (view != null){
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mPresenter = null;
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Fragment was detached");
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {}

@Override
public void onPreLoad() {
    Dialogs.buildLoadingDialog(getContext(), "Loading...").show();
}

@Override
public void onLoad() {}

@Override
public void onDoneLoading() {
    Dialogs.dismiss();
}

}
```

When I enter the method 'moveToFragment()' I just replace CurrentSaleFragment for a new Fragment:

```
protected void addFragment(BaseFragment fragment){
    mView = fragment;
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder,
            fragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Then the new fragment is attached:

```
public class SellProductFragment extends BaseFragment{

private ListView listView;
private ProductListAdapter adapter;
private MainMVP.SalesPresenterOps mSalesPresenter;

public static SellProductFragment newInstance(){
    SellProductFragment fragment = new SellProductFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt(LAYOUT_RES_ID, R.layout.fragment_inventory);
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return fragment;
}

private void reload(){
    final Loader loader = new Loader(this);
    loader.execute();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mSalesPresenter = (MainMVP.SalesPresenterOps)context;
}

@Override
protected void init() {
    super.init();
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_inventory);
    reload();
    FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    addToClickListener(button);
}

@Override
public void onLoad() {
    adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_product_item,
            mSalesPresenter.getProducts());
    try{
        updateListView();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void updateListView(){
    if (adapter != null && listView != null){
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else{
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
}
```

See that This fragment also extends from BaseFragment and implements LoaderRequiredOps. The interface is used to 'load' any data. It adds a dialog and updated the adapter when the loading is done:

```
public class Loader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private LoaderRequiredOps presenter;

public Loader(LoaderRequiredOps presenter){
   this.presenter = presenter;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    presenter.onPreLoad();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    presenter.onLoad();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    presenter.onDoneLoading();
    presenter = null;
}
}
```

Now, when I try to execute the method reload() from the SellProductFragment i get the **'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'**

This does not happen if the SellProductFragment is attached first instead of CurrentSaleFragment.

What is happening here?

Comment: If one particular configuration just happens to not throw that Exception, then you're getting lucky(?). You're ultimately setting an `Adapter` on a `ListView` from `doInBackground()`. You can't do that.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you. Moved 'updateListView()' to 'onPostExecute()'

Comment: Yeah, it would be fine there. `onPostExecute()` runs on the UI thread. (I'm assuming that you've omitted some processing code from `doInBackground()` or `onLoad()` for the sake of a minimal example. If you've not, and that's all you're using the `AsyncTask` for, then it's rather pointless.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an unknown reason, an unidentified configuration allows to execute the setting of an adapter for a `ListView` on the `doInBackground()` method.
Moved it to `onPostExecute()` and now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Your Async Loader class calls the presenters method `onLoad()` from a background thread during `doInBackground()`.

My guess is that in the `onLoad()` method of the presenter, a view is referenced.

In order to change the view at this point, post the view logic as a `Runnable` to the UI thread (you said your presenter is the activity, so this should be possible from the `onLoad` method).

```
@Override
public void onLoad() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your ui code here...
        }
    });

    // Rest of your code here...
}
```